# How to SELECT column using MYSQL operator all values must be available- MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get the value of the column `recipes_id` for values which have entries for `ingredient_id`'s 2,17 and 26.

Suppose the `ingredient_id` 2 is missing then do not get the record.

I have tried the `IN` operator, but it shows the record where any one values are available.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT recipes_id FROM `recipes_ingredient` WHERE ingredient_id IN (2,17,26)
```

This is my current result:

```
+------------+---------------+
| recipes_id | ingredient_id |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             2 |
|          1 |            17 |
|          1 |            26 |
|          3 |             2 |
|          4 |             2 |
|          5 |            26 |
+------------+---------------+
```

This is my desired output:

```
+------------+
| recipes_id |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

Is there any other way I can do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
recipes_id 
FROM 
recipes_ingredient 
WHERE ingredient_id IN (2,17,26)
GROUP BY recipes_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ingredient_id) = 3
```

**Explanation:**

`IN` is just the short form of `OR`.

So, only `IN` doesn't guarantee that a particular `recipes_id` holds all the three.

Since you want result for each `recipes_id` (which meets the condition of course) that's why `GROUP BY recipes_id` comes into play.

Later `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ingredient_id) = 3` is used to filter out only those `recipes_id` which holds all the three `ingredient_id`s given.

<sub>You may leave the `DISTINCT` if `<recipes_id,ingredient_id>` pair is unique.</sub>

Comment: While the above may provide a solution to the question, it would be more useful if you explained what the code exactly does.

Comment: Sure. I always do. :). But I just do it gradually. Thanks!